# How to calculate gradients for RNN hidden states with TensorArray

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I want to calculate the gradient of the loss function with respect to all the hidden states in a 2-dimensional LSTM, which is implemented using `TensorArray` and `tf.while_loop` (refer to [this repo](https://github.com/philipperemy/tensorflow-multi-dimensional-lstm/blob/master/md_lstm.py#L152-L218) for implementation details). The basic idea is that we have one `TensorArray` (with length `time_steps`) to store all the hidden states and we use `tf.while_loop` to calculate hidden states step by step. In the body of the while loop, we calculate `h_t` based on `h_t-1`, like:

```
h_t-1 = h_tensor_array.read(t-1) # read previous hidden states from TensorArray
x_t = x_tensor_array.read(t) # read current input from TensorArray
o_t, h_t = cell(x_t, h_t-1) # RNN cell
h_tensor_array.write(t, h_t) # update hidden states TensorArray
o_tensor_array.write(t, o_t) # update output TensorArray
```

If I simply use

```
all_hidden_states = h_tensor_array.stack() # get all hidden states Tensor
tf.gradients(loss, all_hidden_states) # None
```

(the loss is calculated based on the final hidden states), the gradients are `None`. I suspect that each time we call `stack` or `read` methods of a `TensorArray`, the returned `Tensor`s are **not exactly the same instance**, which mean that they (`h_t-1` and `all_hidden_states`) are **different nodes in the computational graph**. Because we use `h_t-1` in `cell`, there is a path between `loss` and `h_t-1`, but no path exists between `loss` and `all_hidden_states`. Does anyone have an idea about how to get the gradients for all hidden states? Thanks!

Comment: same None error in gradients here, when computing gradients of the hidden states with respect to the input. Have you solved it yet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71107377/tensorflow-obtain-rnn-hidden-states-gradients-with-respect-to-input